# How to add Docstrings in Enum inside Dictionaries

Tags: python, enums, documentation

I use Enums inside dictionaries:

```
Parameters = {
    ONE: Enum(
        value = 'Options',
        names = [
            ('SEPARATE', 0b1),
            ('SEQUENTIAL', 0b0)
        ]
    )
}
```

This style work fits my needs perfectly.

However, when using Enums in a different way, I am able to add docstrings:

```
class ONE(Enum):
    SEPERATE = 0b1
    """The registers associated with each port are separated into different banks"""
    SEQUENTIAL = 0b0
    """The registers are in the same bank (addresses are sequential)"""
```

My question then:

**How can I add docstrings when using Enums inside dictionaries as in the first example?**

**Update**
Testing enum

```
Parameters = {
    'ONE': Enum(
        value = 'ONE',
        names = [
            ('SEPARATE', 0b1),
            ('SEQUENTIAL', 0b0)
        ]
    )
}

print(Parameters['ONE'].SEPARATE)
```

Works as expected

Then attempted to extend Enum()

```
class NewEnum(Enum):
    def __init__(self, **kw):
        super(NewEnum, self).__init__(**kw)


Parameters = {
    'ONE': NewEnum(
        value = 'ONE',
        names = [
            ('SEPARATE', 0b1),
            ('SEQUENTIAL', 0b0)
        ]
    )
}
```

Does not work.

Comment: Overload default constructor and set `__doc__` to each enum member manually.

Comment: Thanks @Olvin, Could you provide a bit more guidance? I found the complete Enum class signature: `Enum(value='NewEnumName', names=<...>, *, module='...', qualname='...', type=<mixed-in class>, start=1)`. For me to override the __Init__ function I will need to know more about the internal construction of the Enum class. However, the documentation does not go into that level of details [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#functional-api)

Comment: Actually, it's pretty simple. You should choose the way, how you want to pass docstring text, e.g. it will be third item of tuple. In your custom constructor you create dict with enum item name as key and docstring as value then you delete third item from oreginal tuples an call regular constructor. After that you iterate over dict you created and set corresponding `__doc__` attribute to each enum item.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Please create an answer of instead of trying to put one in the comments.  Also, please test your answer to make sure it works.

Comment: @EthanFurman, I have no opportunity to launch IDE now, so I point how to achieve required result in comments.

Comment: @OlvinRoght:  Ah, okay.  Your first suggestion of adding the docstring as the third tuple item will not work.

Comment: @EthanFurman, I'm sure that it will. It won't work with original constructor, I've said this option as example.

Comment: @OlvinRoght: I assure you it does not.  The code in `EnumMeta` assumes a two-tuple of `(name, value)` -- changing that to `(name, value, doc)` results in an exception.  However, the second item, `value`, can itself be a tuple, and that's what one must do (along with a custom constructor, of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You aren't setting docstrings, you're writing comments:

```
>>> from enum import Enum
>>> class ONE(Enum):
...     SEPERATE = 0b1
...     """The registers associated with each port are separated into different banks"""
...     SEQUENTIAL = 0b0
...     """The registers are in the same bank (addresses are sequential)"""
... 
>>> ONE.SEPERATE.__doc__
'An enumeration.'
```

So, the easy way is to just add *real* comments:

```
Parameters = {
    ONE: Enum(
        value = 'Options',
        names = [
            ('SEPARATE', 0b1),   # The registers associated with each port are separated into different banks
            ('SEQUENTIAL', 0b0)  # The registers are in the same bank (addresses are sequential)
        ]
    )
}
```

Actually adding `__doc__` using the `type()` format may be a bit harder -- I'll look into it.

---

Okay, here is the custom Enum, `EnumWithDocstring`:

```
class EnumWithDocstring(Enum):
    #
    def __new__(cls, value, doc=None):
        member = object.__new__(cls)
        member._value_ = value
        member.__doc__ = doc
        return member
```

There is nothing fancy going on with the new Enum; the tricky part is realizing that all values passed to the Enum constructor have to be a `tuple`, so your `Parameters` will look like:

```
Parameters = {
    'ONE': EnumWithDocstring(
        value = 'Options',
        names = [
            ('SEPARATE', (0b1, 'test docstring')),
            ('SEQUENTIAL', 0b0)
        ]
    )
}
```

`SEPARATE` has a docstring, but `SEQUENTIAL` does not.

---

Disclosure:  I am the author of the [Python stdlib `Enum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html), the [`enum34` backport](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34), and the [Advanced Enumeration (`aenum`)](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/aenum)  library.

Comment: It bothers me a lot that per-member docstrings are not supported in the core python language.